# How to add Basic Authorization into Header for OAuth2CodeGrantFlow

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I am working on the REST API which needs to get access token from one site. I am using OAuth2CodeGrantFlow jersey implementation. What I need is to set Authorization header before I call **finish** method.

```
OAuth2CodeGrantFlow flow= ... ;
TokenResult tokenResult = flow.finish(code, state);
```

Is there any posibility how to set header for flow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to set an authorization header during your requests to get an authorization token. But if you want to add a header on the request, you can use the Builder class (https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.7/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/client/oauth2/OAuth2CodeGrantFlow.Builder.html) and the property(OAuth2CodeGrantFlow.Phase phase, String key, String value) method.

Comment: This add just a parameter (property) into the request, not into the header. Please give me some example if I am wrong. I am implementing flow to get access token, and there is a need to call flow.finish (second request to server) with Basic Authorization located in header.

Comment: You need two parameters to finish, the code and state. State is easy, you can randomly generate a GUID. Use the builder class to attach the state as a property (use Phase.Authorization). In the finish method, it's just a parameter. You should get a redirect URI returned to you from the start() method, then you can get the code.